# Обновить пользователя

Tags: php

Ребят делаю на PDO. Значит есть пользователь. Если пользователь проходит тест правильно, ему должны засчитаться 10 поинтов. Но поинты не засчитываются, почему,

```html
<?php
   $yes = 0;
   $not = 0;
      if ($_POST[q1] == a){$yes++;} else {$not++;}
      if ($_POST[q2] == a){$yes++;} else {$not++;}
      if ($yes == 2) {
        $score = 10;
        $statement = $db -> prepare ("UPDATE users SET points =:points + $score WHERE id =:id"); 
      }
      echo "<h2>" . $points . "</h2>";
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .test {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 5%;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="test">
    <p>Правильных ответов: <?php echo $yes; ?></p>
<p>Неправильных ответов: <?php echo $not; ?></p>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не обновляете, и даже не передаете параметры для замены bind-параметров.

Правильно делать так:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name=?, surname=?, sex=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt= $dpo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $surname, $sex]);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\Users\Admin\Documents\site\OSPanel\domains\php\result.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Admin\Documents\site\OSPanel\domains\php\result.php on line 14

Comment: Ну вы не копируйте ответ-то бездумно, а под свои реальности подгоняйте.

Comment: Кстати в `execute` падает 3 параметра, а плейсхолдеров 4.